# jQuery converts & into &amp; and breaks my code. How can I stop this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, character-encoding

I am trying to embed a flash movie on a webpage through AJAX using jQuery. The flash movie takes in several commands from the querystring.

Thru an AJAX command jQuery returns HTML code that embeds the flash movie, this code has & in the querystring which then get converted to &amp; - this breaks the code and stops the flash movie from being displayed. The dataType is "text", not "html" in the ajax call.

Ive search around and seen a few people have suffered with this problem. Apparently the main problem is that using .html() or .append() to insert code into a webpage automatically converts & to &amp; - Id like to be able to insert code without this happening. However Id settle for simply converting them back again (which seems to be the main solution to the problem Ive seen), but this isnt working for me at all.

I am running this bit of code to replace all the &amp; with &:

```
$(target+' embed').attr('src',function(){
  var currentHref=$(this).attr('src');
  var newHref=currentHref.replace(/amp;/ig,'');
  return newHref;
});
```

Where target is the Id of the container div the flash movie is in. This code doesnt find any &amp; - but when I view the source the &amp; are still present and the flash movie is still not working.

Id love to be able to insert code without this & to &amp; conversion happening. Can this be done with jQuery? Failing that, how can I get this bit of code to replace all the &amp; with &?

Sorry for the long question and TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bare, unescaped `&` is simply invalid HTML. There is no reason ever to include one in markup.

Any browser, when it sees a `&` that is not part of an entity reference, will fix it up for you to correct your mistake. This happens at parse time, either when loading the document, or on setting `innerHTML` as `html()` and `append()` do.

The browser does not remember your original markup, but only a set of objects and properties (the ‘DOM’) that reflects the current state of the page. These objects are populated by parsing your input HTML, but if you fetch markup by reading `innerHTML` or `html()` you will get a freshly-serialised set of markup created from the DOM objects and **not** the markup you originally put in. You will see differences in whitespace, attribute order, and any mistakes in the original markup will be fixed.

When you interact with the document from script, on the level of properties, `attr()` or `text()`, you're going directly to the DOM without asking it to serialise the information it has back into HTML markup. In that case you will get on-page ampersands as simple `&`, not escaped. So naturally in this case your regexp will not find any to replace; there is simply **no ‘underlying markup’** for you to make edits to.

So the real question is really, what string are you ending up with that is ‘making the code fail’, and how is that being handled? This isn't visible in the posted question.

Comment: Sorry if my original question was unclear! Im new here and still figuring things out. 
Here is an example of the HTML code that I am trying to insert into a page - <param name="movie" value="../swf/contentplayer.swf?u=u123&w=w456&c=4" /> - this then gets translated into - <param name="movie" value="../swf/contentplayer.swf?u=u123&amp;w=w456&amp;c=4" /> which stops the flash movie from working. Is there anyway to insert this code without that translation from happening?

Comment: Again, `value="../swf/contentplayer.swf?u=u123&w=w456&c=4"` is not valid HTML. The browser is completely correct to parse it as the equivalent-but-valid `value="../swf/contentplayer.swf?u=u123&amp;w=w456&amp;c=4"`. This works fine. Your error is elsewhere.

Comment: `http://www.newgateclocks.com/n/z/r/swf/contentplayer-v0.4.swf?u=u4eaedd95b2a2b&w=w4eaede2550c61&c=c4eafb37fd72fc` is the URL. `http://www.newgateclocks.com/n/z/r/swf/contentplayer-v0.4.swf?u=u4eaedd95b2a2b&amp;w=w4eaede2550c61&amp;c=c4eafb37fd72fc` is the HTML-encoded version of the URL. If you include the HTML-encoded version in an HTML attribute such as `<embed src="...">`, it **will** be interpreted as `http://www.newgateclocks.com/n/z/r/swf/contentplayer-v0.4.swf?u=u4eaedd95b2a2b&w=w4eaede2550c61&c=c4eafb37fd72fc` and it **will** work.

Comment: If you need to get a raw, non-HTML-encoded version of the URL then read an embed object's `src` property and leave it at that; don't read `innerHTML`/`html()` because that will naturally be HTML-encoded. (PS. you probably also don't want to use the archaic `<embed>` element.)

Comment: (and yes, im now ditching the archaic <embed> elements!)

Answer (score 0):

If

> target is the Id of the container div the flash movie is in

then the syntax in your first line if off and should be

`$('#target embed').attr('src',function(){`

Comment: sorry, I should of made it clearer, target is a variable that holds the Id of the div container.

Comment: Jimmery: If it is the id as a variable then you forgot the '#'. Try $('#'+target+' embed')

Comment: Ok, for complete clarity the variable target contains a string, which is (in this case) '#modalWindow'. The target variable is honestly not the issue here.